# Is it possible to test a grandchild component in angular tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-unit-test

Right now we are using karma testing to check for existing buttons in a component, the thing is the component displays the buttons as the child of a child.

what we are testing is:

ProductNavComponent
\ NavComponent
\ ButtonComponent

we want to test the button component inside the test component, I've tried using
`await component.findByTestId('import-nav-btn')` and `await component.queryByTestId('import-nav-btn')` but it throws this error in which shows the component html [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWUcw.png) and does show the button I'm trying to test [error image shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOaP0.png) so why is unable to find the button?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a library to be able to use `component.findByTestId('import-nav-btn')` or `component.queryByTestId('import-nav-btn');`. I am thinking it is the `Testing-Library`.

Try changing:

```
<button
 data-test-selector="import-nav-btn"
 ...
>
```

To:

```
<button
  data-testid="import-nav-btn"
  ...
>
```

Because I see them using `data-testid` instead of `data-test-selector` here: https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid/.

That being said, I think you can use Angular's native `fixture` to get a handle on the elements as well.

```
const button: HTMLButtonElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("[data-test-selector='import-nav-btn']")).nativeElement;
```